# Executing a specific Jupyter Lab Notebook on Windows Startup

Tags: windows, jupyter-lab

I have a Jupyter Lab Notebook that I want to execute and run all its steps when the windows server boots up (it is on azure and the machine is shut down during non-working hours).  Has anyone been able to do this?  I want to keep the notebook structure for ease of future changes.

Thanks to all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can :

1. Create a bat file with a command like `jupyter nbconvert --execute --inplace mynotebook.ipynb`
2. Follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44037627/13547620) to set up a job at logon.